# I have dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04, how do i remove 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, removing

I had Ubuntu 12.04 and did a dual boot with 14.04 in case something went wrong with upgrading. It seems to be working fine with either version, so to remove 12.04 leaving just 14.04 should I remove the partition containing 12.04 and run upgrade-grub before rebooting? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your boot partition isn't the one containing the Ubuntu 12.04 boot. If it is, it's better to [move the boot partition to another one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3402/how-to-move-boot-and-root-partitions-to-another-drive).

After that (or if you are sure it isn't the same partition), you can normally [delete the partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310484/how-to-delete-extended-partition-in-ubuntu-12-04) (or using GParted which I recommend) and assign the free space to whatever you'd like.

Try doing those on your installed Ubuntu 14.04 (except moving the /boot because it's mounted), because that way GParted won't let you mess up with Ubuntu 14.04 mounted partitions.

Then you can run repair-boot to delete and update your grub2 settings.

Comment: I edited to add screenshots, I think I need to play with the boot business but thhe links just confused me.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean the screenshot links show a boot on sda2 which I think is the original 12.04 install and when I looked at your move the boot partition link I have no clue what/how to change my boot. !4.04 is sda4 I think. It was the second install.

Comment: ah so you need to move the /boot before deleting the partition. I have never done it myself, but I found those 3 links: [one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3402/how-to-move-boot-and-root-partitions-to-another-drive), [two](http://askubuntu.com/questions/189240/moving-boot-to-a-separate-partition), [three](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1914375).
ps: if you accomplish to move it, don't put it in the ubuntu 14.04 partition because in the future you might want to upgrade system again. the best to do is install the boot in a partition by itself

Comment: I should have maybe just installed 14.04 over 12.04 instead of beside... well thanks for the links, I think I am too nervous to play with grub as I killed 2 other laptops and it took me ages to get them booting again, with this I guess i can just ignore the 12.04 install, i'll never use the drive space, thank you for your time!